# Is there an event for an event starting/ending in Exchange 2013?

Tags: exchange-server

I want to integrate a presence management system (in which users show their status such as "In a Meeting", "At Lunch", "Working on Project", etc) with our Exchange 2013 server.

Is there a way in which I can subscribe and receive an event (API), not of when an event (meeting, etc) is added or removed from a calendar but of when exactly the event (meeting) in the calendar starts and ends?

In other words, what I want to accomplish is that when a user has a meeting that's in their Exchange calendar I listen to that event and automatically change their status in their presence management system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way seamed to be to check the free/busy information (e.g. via Exchange Webservice = EWS).

As you aren´t much specify on your issue I think the best starting point is:

[How to: Get free/busy information by using EWS in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn643673(v=exchg.150).aspx)